# Why is quantity in software still written as "1 result(s)"?

Tags: patterns-and-practices, text-processing

Lately, I've been noticing that a lot of software, be it a website, a client application, or a video game, often write a representation of quantity as follows: "1 result(s)". Now, I can understand why they would do that 20 years ago. But these days, shouldn't we have enough processing power and memory to be able to say "1 result" and "2 results"?

Is there some sort of special reason why it's still done this way?

Now before you tell me to Google it, I would. But the thing is, I have no idea what search terms to use. So even some suggested search terms would be welcome.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Comment: -1: `But these days, shouldn't we have enough processing power and memory to be able to say "1 result" and "2 results"?` - "Processing power" and "memory"?? Seriously?

Comment: I said "memory" because if you're using two different strings, you need to store both of them. And "processing power" because it's an extra comparison that you need to do.

Comment: The memory and CPU overhead is absolutely negligable (and it was 20 years ago too).

Comment: So when exactly did we live in a world where memory was so precious that we couldn't afford to a store an extra string and CPU was so scarce that we couldn't perform an extra comparison? During the time of the ENIAC computer? When we used a slide rule to help us with trigonometry? When we counted with an abacus?

Comment: That's kind of my point. Maybe 20 years ago was a bad example, but since the overhead is negligible, I'm asking why it's still done this way.

Comment: @JimG The Apollo spacecraft had those kinds of problems :-)

Comment: @DanPichelman: I can believe that. I can also believe that memory and CPU were so scarce that developers had to be worried about the "death by a thousand cuts" problem, such that they needed to economize on things wherever they could.

Comment: Astonished nobody has mentioned the [Giant S](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/20684/145673) yet.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Have you considered localization?

It may *look* simple to write something like:

```
var text = (count > 0) ? "items" : "item"
```

But it's nowhere near that simple when you have to work in multiple languages. Here's an example, just using Google Translate:

```
Language        | Singular                  | Plural
----------------+---------------------------+-----------------
English         | 1 item found              | 2 items found
French          | 1 article trouvé          | 2 objets trouvés
Spanish         | 1 artículo encontrado     | 2 artículos encontrados
German          | 1 Artikel gefunden        | 2 Artikel gefunden
Hebrew          | ‭מצא פריט 1                | 2 פריטים נמצאו
Arabic          | ‭وجدت بند 1                | 2 أصناف تم العثور عليها
Korean          | 1 개 항목 발견             | 2 항목 발견
```

Now, granted, Google Translate may not be doing a perfect job here. But isn't that partly the point? This isn't all that simple. You can't just add an "s" and be done with it. Not in production code, anyway. It's *way* simpler to just use the plural form with parentheses - you only have *one* resource to localize that way.

Comment: Localization hadn't even crossed my mind. But then again, I've never worked on a multilingual application before.

Comment: +1 Grammatical number can be very different from one language to another. Some languages have dual (which refers to exactly 2 entities), some languages use a singular form for every number ending with 1 (21, 31, 41, etc.)...

Comment: Just make it easy for yourself in English - select the number of mice you have in inventory.

Comment: I give up on RTL... can't seem to stop the browser from mangling the Arabic and Hebrew text. If anyone can figure it out, go for it. :)

Comment: +1, but I think this might say more about Google Translate than about correct localization. For example, for Hebrew it thinks that when you've got one item, you should say *matsa prit 1* "found 1 item", and when you've got two, you should say *2 pritim nimts'u* "2 items were found". In reality, of course, there's no such distinction: *matsa 2 pritim* "found 2 items" and *prit 1 nimtsa* "1 item was found" are both fine. (Still, *prit 1* "1 item" vs. *2 pritim* "2 items" is genuinely tricky.)

Comment: I don't get it. How makes localization this anymore difficult?

Comment: @ruakh: That's not really Google Translate's fault, it's just a nightmare trying to format a left-to-right table with right-to-left text. I tried and failed to get the number on the right side. If you plug it into Translate you'll see that it's actually correct. My point - which stands regardless of the RTL madness - is that the words themselves are completely different, you can't pluralize by simply adding characters.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. You're saying that if you're dealing with localization, getting the singlular or plural form is harder, so it's ok to just use `(s)`? `(s)` will be completely wrong in many locales, so using that as an excuse  falls pretty flat.

Comment: @Aaronaught: No, no, you're misunderstanding my comment. I noticed the RTL issues, and saw your comment about them, so I looked past them. I'm talking about the actual translation that Google Translate gives: it's drawing a distinction that does not exist, and that therefore isn't relevant to real localization done by humans.

Comment: @BryanOakley You misunderstood.  The English "translation" contains the `(s)`, so the `(s)` is then removed when translated to the other languages.

Comment: @Izkata: I think (s) is wrong and sloppy in english. Translating something wrong into another language will make it wrong there, too. This is just sloppy coding, plain and simple.

Comment: @BryanOakley: That's exactly the *opposite* of what I'm saying. I don't know how anyone could have inferred that from this answer. The point of my answer is that it's easier (and not sloppy) to *localize a single resource that can be either singular or plural* than to actually have to maintain separate singular/plural forms, which might completely change the layout of the text, and also double the amount of test coverage required. Obviously you don't just add an "(s)", but every language has its own equivalent.

Comment: @Aaronaught: I don't understand when you say "every language has it's equivalent". It's wrong in english, so any "equivalent" will be equally wrong in other languages. `(s)` shouldn't be used in English, and equivalents for other languages shouldn't be used either. It's s

Comment: @BryanOakley: It's not *wrong* in English, it just happens to bother a certain type of person. "Seamless" pluralization certainly gives the impression of a higher quality product; as I've demonstrated here, it also comes at quite high a cost compared to the catch-all version. If a programmer is just doing it because he's lazy, then that's one thing - but for many companies and teams (especially those trying to meet tight deadlines) it is a perfectly legitimate business trade-off.

Comment: @BryanOakley The cost is also much higher than you seem to think - it's not as simple as "singular" or "plural".  See lortabac's comment earlier in this thread for just one example.

Comment: @Izkata: in my opinion, `(s)` is _never_ correct. At least if you do it right in English, it's right for one locale. If you use `(s)`, it's wrong in _every_ locale. And let's fact facts, most software unfortunatley doesn't bother with i18n and l9n, so you might as well spend an extra 30 seconds and get it right for _one_ locale.

Comment: @Aaronaught: you say it's not wrong in English. Can you point me to an English grammer reference that say's this is so? I'm not trying to be facetious -- I genuinely want to know if it is considered proper grammar because I've never seen it use anywhere that way except in software.

Comment: @BryanOakley It's called an "optional plural", and is currently right on the border of being acceptable in written English, but isn't yet "official".

Comment: @BryanOakley: It's spelled "grammar". Unfortunate irony for someone being picky about writing style. And yes, it is a form recognized by, for example, the [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Plurals/faq0003.html). There's also an [entire tag dedicated to it](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/parenthetical-plural/hot) on our own English Stack Exchange.

Comment: As well, claiming that "most software doesn't do i18n" hardly justifies the arguments against parenthetical plurals for the *many* businesses that *do*. @BryanOakley, have *you* worked on internationalized or localized software or sites? Can you claim to understand the complexity or effort involved? It sounds to me like you are perhaps in an industry or career niche that does not, and are projecting that onto the rest of the industry. *Most* of the software that we all use on a daily basis has in fact been internationalized.

Comment: This is getting kind of long...take it to [chat] please.

Comment: @Aaronaught: crap! I spelled grammar wrong. *sigh*. Thanks for pointing that out. Of all the words to misspell, right? Yeah, I checked out the wiki pages on it, now that I know what it's called. Unfortunately, none of it convinced me that "1 item(s)" is better than "1 item" when you're dealing with a UI for english speaking people. As to your last question:  yes, I've worked on localized and internationalized software and know the costs associate with it.

Answer (score 6):

Imlementing "1 result(s)" is easier and faster.

EDIT: And it makes the code shorter and therefore easier to understand.

Comment: I see what you mean, but honestly, how much difference would it really make?

Comment: People are very lazy, especially programmers :)

Comment: The edited answer actually sounds like a better reason.

Comment: I find a `printf("%d result%s\n", res, (res == 1) ? "" : "s");` still understandable, and I've used it alot.

Comment: @fhucho's comment is the real answer.

Answer (score -4):

the primary reason is that almost universally in GUI designers there is a distinct separation between pure presentation components and dynamic, data-based presentation components.

eg, you may use a Unchangable label in the static layout of a page.  And this label is really a quite distinct component from a 'field' control.

so, although there are good ways to make the labels themselves dynamic, this is often the very, very, very last step that gets skipped because of time and priority constraints.

And the **natural flow** of most GUI designers is to have this separation beween static and dynamic components, and often  is left that way, unless you specifially go back and QA these kinds of things.

Comment: three down and no comments. interesting.  is there **not** a natural flow to most GUI designers that causes people to layout the static parts of their forms first and plug in dynamic fields next?

Comment: I was with you more or less until the "_natural flow_" comment, which seems like opinion and not fact.  And I upvoted @fhucho's "People are lazy" comment on another answer.